# App crashing when detecting faces in large size images

Tags: android, android-studio, out-of-memory

I am fetching the image from the phone's gallery and setting it in an imageview and using the mobile vision library of google trying to detect the faces in that image. i have also reduced the image size so now the first large size image will get loaded in the image view properly but if you try to load another large size image the app would crash. Also while detecting the faces of large size image the app is crashing in those images the app is getting crashed.

Logcat: [image: logcat]

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.imagegallery.app.imagegallery;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.Face;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {

private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST=1;
Button btnLoad, btnDetFace;
int count=0;
Context cntx;
String open_time,close_time;
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
Bitmap bitmap;
ImageView imageView;
String img_name, realPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cntx=this;
    btnLoad=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_open);
    btnLoad.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDetFace=(Button) findViewById(R.id.detection);
    btnDetFace.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    // Return true to display menu
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent dbmanager = new Intent(this,AndroidDatabaseManager.class);
         startActivity(dbmanager);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_open:
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/* video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            break;
        case R.id.detection:
            if(bitmap == null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bitmap == null",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                detectFace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Done",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            //compressImage(uri);
          //  imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int width = size.x;
            int height = size.y;


            // SDK < API11
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
                realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(this, data.getData());

                // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
                realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(this, data.getData());

                // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4)
            else
                realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, data.getData());

            imageView.setImageBitmap(ImageResizer
                    .decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(realPath, width, height));

            img_name=realPath.substring(realPath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
            count = ++count;

            if (count == 1) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"));
                Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
                DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
                date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"));
                String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);
                open_time = localTime;
            }
            else if (count > 1) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"));
                Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
                DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
                date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"));
                String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);
                close_time = localTime;
                Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                db.addTime(new Time(img_name,open_time, close_time));
                open_time = localTime;
                Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
                List<Time> time = db.getAllData();

                for (Time t : time) {
                    String log = "Start time: " + t.getStartTime() + " ,End Time: " + t.getEndTime();
                    // Writing Time to log
                    Log.d("Time: ", log);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void detectFace(){

    //Create a Paint object for drawing with
    Paint myRectPaint = new Paint();
    myRectPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    myRectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    myRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    //Create a Canvas object for drawing on
    Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

    //Detect the Faces
    FaceDetector faceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

    //!!!
    //Cannot resolve method setTrackingEnabled(boolean)
    //skip for now
    //faceDetector.setTrackingEnabled(false);

    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();

    SparseArray<Face> faces = faceDetector.detect(frame);

    //Draw Rectangles on the Faces
    for(int i=0; i<faces.size(); i++) {
        Face thisFace = faces.valueAt(i);
        float x1 = thisFace.getPosition().x;
        float y1 = thisFace.getPosition().y;
        float x2 = x1 + thisFace.getWidth();
        float y2 = y1 + thisFace.getHeight();
        tempCanvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(x1, y1, x2, y2), 2, 2, myRectPaint);
    }
    imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),tempBitmap));
}
    }
```

Comment: OOM Exception maybe?

Comment: I have attached logcat you can see

Comment: @Neha Which is the line no 114 ?

Comment: Also i need to mention that when adding android:largeHeap="true" in android manifest file the image gets load but as soon as i try to detect the faces the image gets removed from the imageView

Comment: First line in try block is line number 114.
      bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception OutofMemoryError dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032118/exception-outofmemoryerror-dalvik-system-vmruntime-newnonmovablearraynative-met)

Comment: Why post a *screenshot* of your logcat, rather than just the logcat?!

Comment: What is meant by just the logcat?

Answer (score 1):

set following code in manifest file application tag

android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: when adding android:largeHeap="true" in android manifest file the image gets load but as soon as i try to detect the faces the image gets removed from the imageView

Answer (score 0):

Better to compress the image size using bitmap Compress function

tempBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, FileName);

you can adjust compress value as you like.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

You have to use Recycleimageview which is provide by Android for this situation. You can compress bitmap at display time.. Please review given link implment it your issue will resolve.

And android:largeHeap="true" support from Android 3.0 to latest version it does't support to 2.3 version and This is not solution. You have use recycleimage if you want fix issue properly.